# How to send client only the image in the artboard?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard, cc-2017

I had to vectorize a logo for a client but there is stuff outside the artboard that I don’t wish to send them. How do I make it so that the AI file I send them only contains what is in the artboard?

Answer (score 7):

Delete everything you don't want in the file, then save it.

If you want to retain all the stuff outside the artboard for your own reference, then use 
`Save As...` and title the file differently.